# I want to delete marker from my html, css. Its showing on store view

Tags: javascript, css, frontend, phtml, html

I have marker showing in my slider on store view how can I remove it, I can't find this code in html.
[[image: marker shapehtml code]

Comment: You want to check phtml file which show images there.

Answer (score 0):

Your html is broken, you shouldn't have a `<div>` wrapping an `<li>` element. The parent should be a `<ul>` element. If you had the correct `<ul>` element, you would set the css of the `<ul>` to list-style:none;

```
<style>
ul{list-style:none;}
</style>

<ul>
 <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Without fixing your HTML code, its tricky to give an exact fix, but you could try something like:

```
<style>
li::marker {
  color: transparent!important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: thank you for your replaying 
i took this code directly from magento theme home page, its work good in my other (EN store view)
but in (arabic store view i have this marker)
My experience is simple in html and css could you show me the steps for solving that

Answer (score 0):

this is the code from Magento demo directly
[image: magento code]

Comment: This theme has a lot of errors with the html code, I would suggest you raise the issue with the original developers. https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https://portotheme.com/magento2/porto/demo4_en

Comment: how can i reach to all html file because the validator show me all sours code, could you see the photo that i attached to understand what i want

Answer (score -1):

i fixt that by  use the css below in Porto - Setting Panel > Customization Setting:

ul.products li.product-category {
list-style: none;
}

Comment: list-style is meant to be applied to the ul element, not the child li, as per my original answer.

Comment: my html and CSS experience is little, if you can show me the right way to fix that i will be grateful.
not: i couldn't understand how to fix that by your answer,I hope you explain it in a shorter way.
regards